# MPI buffer communication in C

Tags: c, buffer, mpi

```
int SIZE, bsize;
SIZE = 6;

/*the space needed to send data with the number of SIZE and type of MPI_DOUBLE*/
MPI_Pack_size( SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &bsize ); 

/*the space needed for MPI_Bsend*/
tmpbuffer = (double *) malloc( bsize + 2*MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD );

MPI_Buffer_attach( tmpbuffer, bsize + MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD );
```

My question is:

(1)the memory assigned for `tmpbuffer` is `bsize + 2*MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD`, when it comes to `MPI_Buffer_attach`, why its size changes to `bsize + MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD`?

(2)what does 'MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD' mean? And why does it times by `2`?

Comment: In practice: Don't ever bother with buffered mode in MPI. It's practically impossible to use correctly. If you must have an explanation for why third party code does weird things, at least provide more context.

Comment: @Zulan So what does `MPI_Barrier ( MPI_COMM_WORLD )` mean? I see lots of MPI codes have this line.

Comment: Is it just a synchronization that ensures each process has experienced previous expressions?

Comment: We cannot tell you what something *means* without any context! You can easily read what `MPI_Barrier` *does* in the MPI standard and manpages.